# Advise on reading a textfile and looping

Tags: java, file, loops, readfile

Hoping somebody can help a starting Java enthousiast.
I have a text file that looks like this:

```
"AB",101,"ABC","EFG"
"AB",102,"ABC","HIJ"
"AB",103,"ABC","HIJ"
"AB",104,"ABC","XYZ"
"AB",105,"ABC","XYZ"
```

I have read the file with the below code:

```
List<String> list = null;
        try {
            flights = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(pathToFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("No/wrong file");
        }
```

I know have a list where each line is a new element. What I want to do is loop through this list and check each element for the fourth value ("EFG","HIJ" etc.) and remove duplicates.

Would appreciate it if someone can steer me in the right direction.

Comment: Maybe use StringTokenizer, get fourth value, put 4th val in map as key with line as value. Resulting map will have no duplicates

Comment: Loop + split the lines and get 4th element + use a set to only keep distinct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
HashSet<String> alreadyHandled = new HasSet<String>();
for(String line:flights){
    String[] parts = line.split(",");
    String lastPart = parts[parts.length-1]
    if(!alreadyHandled.contains(lastPart)){
        alreadyHandled.add(lastPart);

        //Here you have your code what you want to do with your line
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot. I didn't use the if part though. Since a set doesn't store duplicates anyway.